# Compress wave file in python

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm using Django framework and I received a wave file of size 8MB. I need to reduce the size of the file. How do I do that in python 2?
Note: I have recorder the file through the recorder.js. I didn't find any solution to reduce it through javascript. So I need to reduce its size in python.

Comment: Why not convert it into another format with compression like MP3? As far as I can remember WAV is a raw file and contains every details possible.

Comment: I changed the mimetype to MP3. The type changed but size remains same. Plz tell me how to convert to mp3

Comment: Should be simple with `ffmpeg -i sample.wav sample.mp3`. As an example, I managed to reduce the size of a 247MB .wav file to 22MB .mp3

Comment: Thank you soo much. Can you pls suggest me is there any plugin I use to for conversions through javascript.